# Flutter виджет Slidable не работает callback

Tags: flutter

Учусь Flutter и пытаюсь воспроизвести пример из книги. Но так как в книге версия Slidable старее, а сейчас новее, то у меня не получается.
Вот ошибка: "The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(BuildContext)?'."

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart";
import "package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart";
import "notes_db_worker.dart";
import "notes_model.dart" show Note, NotesModel, notesModel;


class NotesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const NotesList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print("## NotesList.build()");

    // Return widget.
    return ScopedModel<NotesModel>(
        model : notesModel,
        child : ScopedModelDescendant<NotesModel>(
            builder : (inContext, inChild, inModel) {
              return Scaffold(
                // Add note.
                  floatingActionButton : FloatingActionButton(
                      child : const Icon(Icons.add, color : Colors.white),
                      onPressed : () async {
                        notesModel.entityBeingEdited = Note();
                        notesModel.setColor('');
                        notesModel.setStackIndex(1);
                      }
                  ),
                  body : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount : notesModel.entityList.length,
                      itemBuilder : (BuildContext inBuildContext, int inIndex) {
                        Note note = notesModel.entityList[inIndex];
                        // Determine note background color (default to white if none was selected).
                        Color color = Colors.white;
                        switch (note.color) {
                          case "red" : color = Colors.red; break;
                          case "green" : color = Colors.green; break;
                          case "blue" : color = Colors.blue; break;
                          case "yellow" : color = Colors.yellow; break;
                          case "grey" : color = Colors.grey; break;
                          case "purple" : color = Colors.purple; break;
                        }
                        return Container(
                            padding : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                            child : Slidable(

                                startActionPane: ActionPane(
                                  // A motion is a widget used to control how the pane animates.
                                  motion: const ScrollMotion(),

                                  // A pane can dismiss the Slidable.
                                  dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {}),

                                  // All actions are defined in the children parameter.
                                  children: [
                                    // A SlidableAction can have an icon and/or a label.
                                    SlidableAction(
                                      onPressed: _deleteNote(inContext, note),
                                      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      icon: Icons.delete,
                                      label: 'Delete',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child : Card(
                                    elevation : 8,
                                    color : color,
                                    child : ListTile(
                                        title : Text("${note.title}"),
                                        subtitle : Text("${note.content}"),
                                        // Edit existing note.
                                        onTap : () async {
                                          // Get the data from the database and send to the edit view.
                                          notesModel.entityBeingEdited = (await NotesDBWorker.db.get(note.id)) as int;
                                          notesModel.setColor(notesModel.entityBeingEdited.color);
                                          notesModel.setStackIndex(1);
                                        }
                                    )
                                ) /* End Card. */
                            ) /* End Slidable. */
                        ); /* End Container. */
                      } /* End itemBuilder. */
                  ) /* End End ListView.builder. */
              ); /* End Scaffold. */
            } /* End ScopedModelDescendant builder. */
        ) /* End ScopedModelDescendant. */
    ); /* End ScopedModel. */

  } /* End build(). */


  Future _deleteNote(BuildContext inContext, Note inNote) async {

    print("## NotestList._deleteNote(): inNote = $inNote");

    showDialog(
        context : inContext,
        barrierDismissible : false,
        builder : (BuildContext inAlertContext) {
          return AlertDialog(
              title : const Text("Delete Note"),
              content : Text("Are you sure you want to delete ${inNote.title}?"),
              actions : [
                TextButton(child : const Text("Cancel"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Just hide dialog.
                      Navigator.of(inAlertContext).pop();
                    }
                ),
                TextButton(child : const Text("Delete"),
                    onPressed : () async {
                      // Delete from database, then hide dialog, show SnackBar, then re-load data for the list.
                      await NotesDBWorker.db.delete(inNote.id);
                      Navigator.of(inAlertContext).pop();
                      Scaffold.of(inContext).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                              backgroundColor : Colors.red,
                              duration : Duration(seconds : 2),
                              content : Text("Note deleted")
                          )
                      );
                      // Reload data from database to update list.
                      notesModel.loadData("notes", NotesDBWorker.db);
                    }
                )
              ]
          );
        }
    );

  } /* End _deleteNote(). */


} /* End class. */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаёте некорректное выражение в параметр `onPressed` у `SlidableAction`. Вам следует указать анонимную функцию или метод, вызывающий действие `_deleteNote()`, например, вот так:

```
SlidableAction(
  onPressed: (context) => _deleteNote(context, note),
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
  icon: Icons.delete,
  label: 'Delete',
)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!